# How to hide slider value

Tags: win-universal-app

I want to hide slider value.

I tried to change the template, but I didn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Slider* has [IsThumbToolTipEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.isthumbtooltipenabled) property. Setting it to *false* should do the job.